# How to load backbone.babysitter?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

In my project I would like to use [backbone.babysitter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter), but I can't make it work.

I use `require.js` to load the modules, now my config looks like this.

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
    'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
    'backbone.babysitter': 'lib/backbone.babysitter',
    'jquery': 'lib/jquery',
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: '_'
    },

    backbone: {
      deps: ['underscore','jquery'],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    }

  }
});
```

I use the AMD version of `backbone.babysitter`
When I do later in my code

```
require( ['backbone.babysitter'], function(){
  var v = Backbone.ChildViewContainer();
});
```

I got the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_updateLength' backbone.babysitter.js:41`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it work with not the AMD version of the lib like this.
under shim:

```
'backbone.babysitter': {
  deps: ['backbone','underscore']
},
```

and require like this:

```
require( ['backbone.babysitter'], function(){
  var v = new Backbone.ChildViewContainer();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `backbone.babysitter` depends on backbone and underscore you should state that between your dependencies:

```
'backbone.babysitter': {
  deps: ['backbone', 'underscore']
}
```

since `backbone` already depends on `unserscore` and `jquery`:

```
'backbone.babysitter': {
  deps: ['backbone']
}
```

would be sufficient.

Comment: You mean under shim? I think not, because I'm using the AMD version of `backbone.babysitter`, where it's already defined. regarding the require.js [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim). The backbone and underscore libraries are loaded, I checked that.

Comment: @balazs yes, under shim. I would definitely try the non amd version of that plugin to see is it related to modular loading or something else.

Comment: I already tried, I think it's a kind of bug in backbone.babysitter. The _updateLength method is added to the `Container.prototype`, while `this` is refers to `Backbone.ChildViewContainer` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing it to the function as parameter, but also you need to pass backbone:

```
require( ['backbone'], function(Backbone){
   var v = Backbone.ChildViewContainer();
});
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Babysitter doesn't exports anything, it's just a plugin for Backbone, no need for passing a variable, actually tried, but doesn't work `Babysitter` is `undefined`.

Comment: you are right, I made the an update in the code I think just passing backbone will sufice